# Oracle export default date

Tags: oracle, backup, exp

I am trying to export data from oracle but i cant get the latest updates.I am newbie on oracle so don't get angry
Is it a default time for export i mean like specific history(1 week before?)
I created a table last week but i cant get this table in this export file. 
Also there are new values in these tables but i cant get this value too.
I am using this code:

```
exp SYSTEM/password FILE=tables.dmp TABLES(sometable) GRANTS=y INDEXES=y log=exp.log
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're including the table in your export? If you are using the Tables parameter, you must list the table in question, otherwise it will not be included in your export. Is the table that you're missing included in "sometable"?

Comment: There isn't a default time for export, no, it will include all (committed) data in all the objects you specify at the point you execute the command. Hopefully you didn't create your own table in the `SYSTEM` schema though? That would be a bad idea. If you created it in another schema (good) then export as that user, not as `SYSTEM`. And if you see the tables in the log but with zero rows, you may have uncommitted data, or might be connected to the wrong DB, or might be looking at similar tables in the wrong schema.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex. I understand my problem.